# Is correct expression "gone her/him/me"?

Tags: adjectives, pronouns

I've watched the movie "gone girl".
However, I thought that how about "gone her".
Then, I'm not sure that correct English expression "gone her".

There is the move title, "Despicable me". That word is constructed Adjective + Objective Pronouns. That means "gone her" is also constructed same with the above case. However,  "gone" is kind a past adjective and doesn't not express a emotional feelings but expresses action or situation. I think Adjective + Objective pronouns case is a kind of limited expression.

Please answer me "gone her" is correct English expression.

Comment: No, it's not correct. The title, 'Gone Girl,' is a fragment and ambiguous (likely purposefully so). But regardless, there's no case where "gone her" is a valid expression.

Answer (score -1):

I can't post comments yet, so I'm leaving an answer that would probably fit better as a comment.

Participles and gerunds are called nominal forms in some languages because they have such syntactical functions as nouns, adjectives and adverbs do. Compare

> ***Hitchhiking*** is not allowed in the U.S.

and

> ***Animals*** are not allowed inside.

for a present participle working as a subject, and

> *The boy was **gone** / The **gone** boy.*

and

> *The boy ran away / The **runaway** boy.*

for an adjective-like example.

In short, *the gone girl* is just as correct as *the girl that is gone*.

And finally, to answer your question, I think it would be correct should the word order be switched -- "I imagined her gone, heading somewhere east of here", though I'm not sure "I imagined a gone her, heading somewhere east of here" would be incorrect (though I lack the practical example I've seen similar constructions somewhere).

As I said, this would have been a much better comment than it is an answer, but I hope it helps!

Comment: This doesn't answer the question which is about *gone her*. Please [edit] it to address that question.

Comment: I hadn't noticed the last paragraphs went missing -- copy-paste failure. Thanks for pointing it out.